# How can I get a substring between 2 another substrings in Python

Tags: python, string, substring

How can I get the content between two substrings?
For example in `"Hello, I have a very expensive car"` I want to find the content between
`"Hello, I have"` and `"car"`, no matter what it is.
How can I find the substring between the two strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions to the rescue:

```
import re

text = "Hello, I have a very expensive car"

pattern = re.compile(r'(?P<start>Hello, I have)(?P<middle>.+?)(?P<end>car)')

match = pattern.search(text)
if match:
    print(match.group('start'))
    print(match.group('middle'))
    print(match.group('end'))
```

Which yields (the spaces are intended):

```
Hello, I have
 a very expensive 
car
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/LnM8QZ/1).

---

To have a variable text, you could make use of f-strings as in:

```
myVariable = "Hello, I have"
pattern = re.compile(rf'(?P<start>{myVariable})(?P<middle>.+?)(?P<end>car)')
```

Comment: How can I use this just with variable, like (?P<start>myVariable) ?

Comment: @alondavidi: Updated the answer, use f-strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
s = 'Hello, I have a very expensive car'
s = s.split(' ')

print(' '.join(s[s.index('have')+1:s.index('car')]))
```

Output:-

```
'a very expensive'
```

Comment: It's ok but what if I have a big string ?

Answer (score 0):

try 're' module of Python for regular expressions:

```
import re

my_string = 'Hello, I have a very expensive car'
res = re.search('Hello, I have(.*)car', my_string)
print(res.group(1))
```

Answer (score -1):

You could just remove the 2 strings in case there is no other text around

```
value = "Hello, I have a very expensive car"
res = re.sub("(Hello, I have|car)", "", value).strip()
print(res) # a very expensive
```